# An error occurred with Google Calendar API insufficientPermissions

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-api-client

I refer to the document https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert to call the insert method, but there is an error `insufficientPermissions`. I want to know what the general situation is, and I can use `gapi.client.calendar.events.list()` method to get the result normally.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using one of the [Calendar API Quickstarts](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/js) which is why calls to `events.list` works but `events.insert` doesn't. You need to change the scope to `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar` because that is required for `events.insert`.

Also don't forget to delete the previously saved credentials when adding the new scope.